# General Cone Gaze Constraint

Tags: constraints, robotics, drake

I've been using the [gaze constraint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_gaze_target_constraint.html) in order to do inverse kinematics for seeing objects with a camera. However, and I imagine I am not alone in this manner, the output of my camera is square. Because the constraint only allows for circular cones, it only includes about half the area that the camera sees.

I was wondering if it would be possible to introduce a gaze constraint that works with a general purpose cone? If solving such a general problem isn't practical, a gaze constraint that accepted elliptical cones would be a really useful alternative as a user can effectively implement a rectangular cone (using two elliptical cones, each with one arbitrarily large axis).

Comment: I can add a new constraint to accept a polyhedron cone in the form A * x < = 0, where each row of that A matrix is the outward normal vector of the polyhedron cone. This polyhedron cone can capture your square camera output region, where the cross section area of this polyhedron cone can be a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `PolyhedronConstraint` to Drake's inverse kinematics code. It can handle "target in the rectangle gaze cone". I also added an [example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6dbcc33e9b71ca93986744306be24fc33c25492a/multibody/inverse_kinematics/test/polyhedron_constraint_test.cc#L93-L135) to show how to use this constraint.

Comment: Thanks so much!I 

I do notice though that, at least in Python, the init of AddPolyhedronConstraint requires that `p_GP: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[3, n], flags.f_contiguous]` and `A: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, n], flags.f_contiguous]`. It seems to me though that `A` should be `[m, 3]`, not `[m, n]`. Is that correct or am I confused?

Comment: The size of A is [m, 3*n]. The idea is to impose the constraint A * [p_FP.col(0); p_FP.col(1);... p_FP.col(-1)] <= b, namely the stacked column vector of p_FP. I guess you might think the constraint as A * p_FP.col(0) <= b, A * p_FP.col(1) <= b... which isn't the case.